# CSS Zoom image always on top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have generated a simple CSS code to get an enlarged image when the users hovers over the image.

```
.zoom:hover {
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
  -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
  -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
  transform:scale(1.25);
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #999999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px #999999;
}
```

The result is nice but sometimes an image is not shown on the top, how to prevent this from happening? I have tried adding `position: relative;` and `position: absolute;` to the `css`code.

[image]

```
<div class="col-lg-9 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">

    <h4 style="padding-top: 25px;"><strong>Vaste filters</strong></h4>
    <blockquote><p class="description" style="font-size: 14px;">
    Er kunnen voor modules ook vaste filers in de code worden verwerkt, om bijvoorbeeld alleen projecten te zien welke op dit moment lopen of die om een andere actie vragen.
    </p>

    <img src="img/portfolio/torza/007.png" class="img-fluid zoom" alt="Torza">
    </blockquote>

</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 mt-auto mb-auto">

    <img src="img/portfolio/torza/006.png" class="img-fluid zoom" alt="Torza">

</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for, with the amount of questions you've asked already i would assume by now you'd know how to ask a question, add a code snippet illustrating  the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding **z-index** Property

```
.zoom:hover {
  transform:scale(1.25);
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #999999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px #999999;
  /* To bring top */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
 }
```

But make sure everything gets organised by z-index, even the dropdowns. Because `z-index` act like hierarchy.

Say for example,
If you add `z-index: 0;` content will go behind the `z-index: 1;` content.